# VNC - Is there any way to turn off logging/log files

Tags: log-files, vnc

I've looked everywhere for a solution to this. Is there any way to turn off this logging in VNC?

VNC seems to be logging some large updates I'm doing in mysql and taking up my whole hard drive space. The only way to get rid of the log file is to reboot, which I would prefer not to have to do if possible.

Cheers

Comment: What OS? What version and type of VNC (RealVNC, TightVNC, UltraVNC, Chicken of the VNC, etc.)?

Comment: RealVNC, Centos/Linux i can see a .vnc folder in root, but there doesnt seem to be any options i can configure

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I get the connection between VNC and MySQL here, but if you want to stop something logging to a file, make the log file a soft link to /dev/null.  If a process is logging to syslog, you can either edit the syslog config file to make it stop logging that process, or simply kill syslog outright.

Logs are good for figuring out what problems you are having on the system.  Usually high log load, on a non-debug enabled system, is an indication of something going horribly wrong.